# Is there a more C++ way to get the EOF code?

Tags: c++

In C, `EOF` is a macro defined in `stdio.h`. I wonder is there a C++ equivalent to it (a `const int` or sth)?

What do I want it for? For example, I may want to implement a `SeekEof()`:

```
// Is there any non-space character remaining?
bool SeekEof(std::istream &in) { 
  int c(0);
  while ((c = in.peek()) != EOF &&
         (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || 
          c == '\r' || c == '\n')) in.get();
  return c == EOF ;
}
```

Comment: How are you reading it? There is usually a way to check for EOF flag. Please be specific.

Comment: I think you are wondering about the data type of EOF, so, I think it's boolean: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/eof/

Comment: @facunvd: `EOF` is of type `int`, and typically has the value `-1`. Your link refers to `eof`, specifically `std::ios::eof`, which is different; it's similar to C's `feof()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::char_traits<char>::eof()
std::char_traits<char16_t>::eof()
std::char_traits<char32_t>::eof()
std::char_traits<wchar_t>::eof()
```

Comment: It's usually less verbose because in the context where you use it, there's already some `std::...<chartype>` type from which you can derive this. E.g. `std::string` has a `traits_type` member which is short for `std::char_traits<char>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stdio.h` also in your c++ application. But beware of using it. its stupid (-1) macro and -1 to byte is 255 (0xff). If you check input character to EOF, you can end with result of false end of file. Safe check for `eof` is using feof() in c/c++ and .eof() methods in c++.

Comment: +1. Never read a `char` and compare to `EOF`, always read an `int` and convert to `char` later.

Comment: It's not stupid, but it can be used stupidly. For example, `getchar()` returns an `int` result, which is *either* a byte read from stdin interpreted as a `unsigned char` and converted to `int` *or* the negative value `EOF`. Misusing `getchar()` by assigning its result to a `char` will cause problems, but that's the fault of the caller, not of the `getchar()` function. And `feof()` is different; it becomes true only *after* you've attempted to read past the end of the stream, and it *doesn't* become true if there's an error.

Answer (score 1):

When reading from a file or other stream using C's `<stdio.h>` functions, `EOF` is a special value returned by certain functions to flag an inability to read any more data, either because you've reached the end of the file *or* because there was an error. There are `feof()` and `ferror()` functions, but these should only be used *after* you've detected and end-of-file or error condition, to distinguish one from the other.

For example, the classic C input loop is:

```
int c; /* Note int, *not* char */
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    /* do something with c */
}
/* optional: */
if (ferror(stdin)) {
     /* an error occurred, not just end-of-file */
}
```

C++'s has several different overloaded `std::istream::get()` functions. One of them takes no arguments and behaves very similarly to C's `getchar()`: it returns an `int` value which will be `EOF` if no more data is available:

```
int c;
while ((c = std::cin.get()) != EOF) {
   // do something with c
}
```

You'll have to have `#include <cstdio>` to get the definition of `EOF`.

Another overloaded version takes a reference to a `char` and returns an `istream&` result that can be tested to tell whether it was able to read anything:

```
char c;
while (std::cin.get(c)) {
    std::cout << c;
}
```

There is an `eof()` function (specifically `std::ios::eof()`) that tells you whether the end-of-file flag is set. There are several other state functions: `good()`, `fail()` and `bad()`. [See here for more information.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/)

*(NOTE: Is cplusplus.com considered a good resource? If not, let me know and I'll change the link.)*

In any case, the state functions (`feof()` and `ferror()` for C I/O, `eof()`, `fail()`, `bad()`, `good()` for C++ I/O) should not be used as loop conditions; instead, loops should be controlled by the result you get when you attempt input, and the other functions can be used *after* the loop terminates to determine why it terminated.

Comment: Lots of people here say that cppreference.com is preferred to cplusplus.com.

Comment: BTW, why would he want to use stdio in code that already uses iostreams? The `peek` function returns `std::istream::traits_type::eof()` as the eof value as specified [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek).

Answer (score 0):

std::fstream fileHandle.eof()
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/eof/